# Struggling to extract a specific month of DATE(s) from a Timestamp field in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, sql-timestamp

Just started my very first data analyst job this week!
My first bigquery is hitting a lot of snags:
I need to somehow extract a specific set of dates from a timestamp field.

**Specifically:**
I need to extract all of the dates for the month of December, so the range of December 1, 2020 - December 31, 2020 from the timestamp data. I tried the formulas from these two other stackoverflow entries:

I forgot to include how the data looks: *2020-12-12 16:36:58.944 UTC* and just want to get back the date '2020-12-2-01 - 2020-12-31' ultimately.

**1.** [Extracting date from timestamp in Bigquery: a preferable method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933531/extracting-date-from-timestamp-in-bigquery-a-preferable-method)
**2.** [BigQuery: extract date from datetime with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175974/bigquery-extract-date-from-datetime-with-timezone)

**Code I tried**
*SELECT
EXTRACT(DATE FROM PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z', '11/27/2019 14:40:15 CET +0100')) AS date*

I don't understand how to extract just the date part of the timestamp and then how to only extract or arrange the dates so that my query only returns the values from the month of December.

Halp! I tried using an Extract function and a Trunc function but nothing works.

I'm still learning the correct/most understandable way to ask my questions, too so all tips to clarify are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select *, 
from `project.dataset.table`
where date_trunc(date(parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z',ts)),month)='2020-12-01'
```

to test, play with above you can use below toy example

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
    select 1 id, '11/27/2020 14:40:15 CET +0100' ts union all 
    select 2, '11/29/2020 14:40:15 CET +0100' union all 
    select 3, '11/30/2020 14:40:15 CET +0100' union all 
    select 4, '12/10/2020 00:20:15 CET +0100' union all 
    select 5, '12/20/2020 00:40:15 CET +0100' union all 
    select 6, '12/25/2020 14:40:15 CET +0100' union all 
    select 7, '12/27/2020 14:40:15 CET +0100' union all 
    select 8, '01/02/2021 14:40:15 CET +0100' union all 
    select 9, '01/04/2021 14:40:15 CET +0100' 
)
select *, 
    date(parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z', ts)) date,
    date_trunc(date(parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z', ts)), month) month
from `project.dataset.table`
where date_trunc(date(parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z',ts)),month)='2020-12-01'
```

with output

[image]